# Print out the index of all occurrences of a string in an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have created a simple PHP script where the user types in a sentence (or sentences) and the script takes each word from the textarea and splits it up into an array. The user will also type in a word to search for in the array.

The script should look through the array and print out the index of all places where the word is.

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach($parts as $item) {
       if ($item == $strName) {
           $k = array_search($strName, array_values($parts));
           print "$k\n";
       }

}
```

However that only prints out the first index location of the string. So if the sentence I use is "The apple fell from the tree", it will just print out "0 0", which is the first time the word appears in the array (it also does the same if the index is 1, 2, 3, etc). Is there something that I have done wrong? Sorry if I didn't include enough information.

Entire code:

```
    <form action="sida3.php" method="post">
    Text: <textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
    <br>
    Search word: <input type="text" name="search">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $parts = explode(" ", $_POST['textarea']);
    $strName = $_POST['search'];
    print_r ($parts);
    echo '<br>';
    foreach($parts as $item) {
        if ($item == $strName) {
            print_r(array_keys($parts, $strName));
        }
    }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: what value is $item? String or Array?  I'm assuming you are overcomplicating what you're trying to do.  Outside of finding the instances, what are you trying to do with them once found?

Comment: `print_r(array_keys($parts, $strName));`

Comment: @joeb once the location of the strings have been found it's supposed to say "Input string was found at 0 4" and also "string was found 2 times". Item is string from the array

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
function search_array( $needle,  $string ){
    $haystack = explode( " ", $string);
    $keys_found = array_keys( array_map( "strtolower", $haystack) , strtolower( $needle ), false);
    if( !empty( $keys_found ) ):
        return array(
                    "count" => count( $keys_found ),
                    "keys" => $keys_found
                );
    else:
        return false;
    endif;
}

var_dump( search_array("Every","Every good boy does fine, every good girl does fine") );
```